# Can I use the Parcel.JS bundler when setting up Firebase on my Javascript application?

Tags: javascript, firebase, parceljs

So I'm trying to connect my Javascript application to Firebase. I understand that I need to use a bundler to do this, and my preferred method is Parcel.JS. I run my Parcel.JS script with the following code in my package.json file:

```
  "main": "./public/js/bundle.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --dist-dir ./public/js",
```

This is the code in my index.js file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAnalytics } from 'firebase/analytics';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: '',
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Parcel.JS bundles it up into bundle.js as expected, and I reference it at the bottom of my index.pug file as follows:

```
script(src='/js/bundle.js')
```

When the page loads, I check the console in Chrome and see the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at bundle.js:1
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: The error you received is because you didn't define something on line 1 in your `bundle.js` file.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to use the `"main"` field in `package.json`. According to [the documentation](https://parceljs.org/getting-started/library/#commonjs-and-es-modules), this is intended for people who develop libraries (e.g. npm packages that are consumed by others), which doesn't sound like you. Specifically, the `"main"` field tells parcel to output a commonjs bundle at that location, which would help explain why you are seeing errors about `require` calls, which won't run in the browser.

Another possible source of trouble is the fact that your `dist-dir` directory is the same location as your source `js` (`./public/js`) - I havn't been able to test this because npm is down at the moment, but what I think that might cause parcel to overwrite your source files?

I'd recommend removing the `main` field from `package.json` and moving your source code to a different directory than the `--dist-dir` target.